# What is wrong with my list index? index error is stated

Tags: python-3.3, traceback

```
numbers = []

def easy_mode():
    with open("aa.txt","r") as f:
        for i in range(9):
            numbers.append(f.readline().strip())
        print(numbers)

 from random import randint

 for i in range(9):
    print(numbers[randint(0,8)])
```

when ever i process this into python the program prints out this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "N:\Yr 10 CP\Practice\python\Gaming\THE ACTUAL THING.py", line 12, in <module>
    print(numbers[randint(0,8)])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

can someone please help me and try and fix my code for me, thanks

Alberto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This tabbing is wierd so im not completely sure what is inside the function, but i think that

```
from random import randint

for i in range(9):
    print(numbers[randint(0,8)])
```

is outside of the function and my guess is that you didn't call the function but just loaded the script and it started executing skipping the function and in the end the *numbers* variable is empty and therefore any index is out of range.

EDIT:
So the working version of the code should look like (given that the file indeed contains at least 9 lines):

```
numbers = []

def easy_mode():
    with open("aa.txt","r") as f:
        for i in range(9):
            numbers.append(f.readline().strip())
        print(numbers)

from random import randint

easy_mode()
for i in range(9):
    print(numbers[randint(0,8)])
```

Comment: Thanks @crollywood for your reply, i will change that piece of code and see what happens, if your suggestion doesn't seem to fix the code could you give me an alternative to do?

Comment: You're welcome! It should be all correct after you rearange the code, but if you do happen to have problems just say what is it and I'll do my best to help you.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be multiple errors here. For one thing, you are assuming, in your first loop, that the file has at least 9 lines, which might not be true. More importantly, you are never calling `easy_mode`, so `numbers` is in fact empty in your second loop

Comment: The file 'aa.txt' does have 9 lines, and the function is called later on in the code, the file has 9 words each placed on a separate line, i don't know if this is causing a problem

Comment: Then use: `numbers = open("aa.txt").readlines()`, and then `for in range(len(numbers))`

Comment: I am not sure whether you expected your last loop to show the words in any order, but that's not what you are doing. You might end up with duplicates and missing words, in the final output. Search for "random permutation" instead, perhaps `random.shuffe(numbers)`